# WPF: 2 different label sizes in particular order alignment

Tags: wpf, alignment, label

Please take a look at this picture:

[image]

I try to create same label with 2 sizes:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="11" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" />
    <Label Content="%" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="20"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

But currently this is not like the picture:

[image]

Comment: What do you get instead? I assume that what you get is that the percent sign is on the right, far from your `11`.

Comment: Can you put them in separate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have such a result, your grid must be really small. I see at least 3 solutions to your issue:

1- Make your grid a bit bigger until it fits.

2- Put 2 columns in your grid, you'd put the number on the left column and the % on the right columns.

3- You could use a StackPanel like this:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="11" FontSize="50" Padding="0"/>
        <Label Content="%"  FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0,10,5,5"/>
    </StackPanel>        
</Grid>
```

EDIT:

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Veritical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="11" FontSize="50" Padding="0"/>
            <Label Content="%"  FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0,10,5,5"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Storage">
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: OK that works fine but the sign '%' is a little right than i want, is it possible to move it closer to the number ?

Comment: Which solution did you try?

Comment: If you've used the StackPanel, you could put the Padding of the first label to 0 and the padding of the % label to 0,10,5,5.
I have updated my solution to include it.

Comment: BTW if i want to add nother label like in te example ? (the label between the '11% 'and the line STOREAGE)

Comment: You could add a second "layer" of stackpanel, look at my Edit.